Inherit args from the main wp_query or wp_comment_query to my custom query
I want to create a custom wp query, inheriting the args of the main query both for wp_query and the wp_comment_query.
I can't find the right way to do it.
WP QUERY:
$args = array(
 // custom args
)

// Here I need some method to join main query args and my custom args

$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );

WP COMMENT QUERY:
$args = array(
 // custom args
)

// Here I need some method to join main query args and my custom args

$comments_query = new WP_Comment_Query( $args );
$comments = $comments_query->comments;

This because I want to keep all default args and settings (admin settings), I need all default args and I have to set just few custom args keeping default args.
Thanks
I tried this, but there aren't all query vars like 'post_status' is missing.
//Store the query vars in a variable
$query_vars = $wp_query->query_vars;

//Edit the tag_id
$query_vars['post_type'] = 'another-type';

//create new wp_query
$new_query = new WP_Query($query_vars);


"but there aren't all query vars like 'post_status' is missing" - does your main query have that explicitly set to a specific value, or is it just using the default? If it is just using the default, then it might not show up in the query_vars property, I suppose - but that should then not matter, because any new query you make with the same arguments, should then also use the default value ...?

@CBroe no the value is not explicitly entered, so as you say it may not be inside query_vars, but the query gets a different result from the main query

When does your custom code run - is the main query already executed at this point? Or could it be it is earlier, and that other plugins are still hooking into pre_get_posts or something, to modify query parameters?

@CBroe How should I know? I am developing a theme that should also be compatible with this type of problem
